# how can change the font colour in drop-down in a w2uigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
{background: #efefef;color:#333;font-size:11px;font-style: normal;}

<select style=\"width:100%\" name=\"selectedUomValue('+record.recordKey+')\"  o styleClass=\"readonly\" disabled=\"true\" >'; \n "
   +"}else{"
  +"selectTag='<div style=\"text-align:center\">"
   +"<select style=\"width:100%\" >';\n"
```

i have tried tyhis but i the colour in different in IE9,IE10,IE11, browsers when compared to crome and firefox

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet.

Comment: i suggest you add a class with the desired color rather than inline style

Comment: i  have tried it but the font colour is different when compare to other browsers